# MVC Html.TextBoxFor MaxLength and Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, model, lambda, maxlength, html.textboxfor

I am trying to setup a TextBox control in my project using Html.TextBoxFor.

However, it only seems to have method signatures for either:

Lambda Expression and Value:

```
 <%= Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.ProjectDetails.Title, Model.ProjectDetails.Title)%>
```

or

Lambda Expression and HtmlAttributes:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.ProjectDetails.Title, new { maxlength = 10})%>
```

This is not an issue for styling as the control id is known:  ProjectDetails_Title and a style sheet can be used. However, maxlength cannot be set via CSS as it is a behavior.

I know you can specify all three using Html.Textbox but I want to take advantage of the extra functionality of Html.TextBoxFor.

Any ideas on how I can set both a value AND a maxlength for a control rendered using Html.TextBoxFor?

Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This should work in MVC4. Not sure about MVC2.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.ProjectDetails.Title,new { @maxlength="10", @class="myCssClass"})
```

Comment: You are correct it works in MVC2 as well.  I was thinking you needed both the lambda expression and a separate property for the value. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Hi this is not working with me, any possible solution?